# Nuxt 3 after building : [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/anynonexistingroute"

Tags: nuxt3

I built a nuxt 3 project using npm run build and i`m running it with "node .output/server/index.mjs", just to test it. But when I make a request to a inexistent route, this warning is outputed to the terminal, and I think that on production it would slow down the performance. How can I fix this, or at least disable terminal logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem creating some "composable" and using the code below to verify if you are in production environment to after remove the logs:

example:

// useProduction.ts

```
export default function () {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        console.warn = function () {};
    }
}
```